# how to find which part of js is slowing the page down

Tags: javascript, profiling

hi my page is taking about 9s on local server and about 20s on remote server, i am sure that the problem is in js, but i can't find what makes it slow, can you please help me find a solution or any tool to hunt the problem down?

Comment: Only one of your six other questions has received an acceptable answer?

Comment: yes mostly because i had to use my own solutions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the modern major browsers have js profiling builtin now.
[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/javascript) & [Chrome](http://blog.chromium.org/2009/06/developer-tools-for-google-chrome.html) both have good client script profiling tools, also they have http traffic monitors which may also help you diagnose the issue. [IE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/11/introducing-the-ie8-developer-tools-jscript-profiler.aspx) also has one.

Here is an example of the firebug profiler in action
[image]

[EDIT]In Chrome, press Ctrl+Shift+J to open the JavaScript profile page.

Comment: i am already using it buddy :) it tells me which file is taking load but i need to find the part/function/line whatever is it that is making the file load slow :) thanks for your help anyway

Comment: @user503148 well buddy your not looking at the correct screen. The tools given above profile each javascript method executed giving you detailed timings.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to built-in or add on profiling tools (the preferred way I'd say): use a timer. 
I've cooked up this one:

```
 function Timer(){
  var start = new Date
      ,ended = 'running ...';
  return {
      start: function(){
              start = new Date; 
              return this
      },
      stop:  function(mssg) {
              var stoppedAt = (new Date - start);
           ended = [(mssg ? mssg+': ' : '')
                           ,(stoppedAt/1000)+' sec (+/- 15ms)'].join('')
              return ended;
      }
      ,toString: function(){
                return ended;
      }
  };
}
//usage:
var timenow = new Timer().start();
// run a function
console.log(timenow.stop('this took '));
```

You can also use a wrapper function to time the execution time of a function. Something like:

```
function timedFn(fn){
  var timer = new Timer().start();
  fn();
  console.log(timer.stop('function took '));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i will add [Web developer 1.1.8](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/) Add on for Firefox with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/javascript) & [Chrome](http://blog.chromium.org/2009/06/developer-tools-for-google-chrome.html)

For more details have a look on this [link](http://amiworks.co.in/talk/11-best-web-developer-tools-for-firefox-and-internet-explorer/)

with regards

**Wazzy**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) for Firebug. From the YSlow page:

> YSlow analyzes web pages and suggests ways to improve their performance based on a set of rules for high performance web pages. YSlow is a Firefox add-on integrated with the Firebug web development tool. YSlow grades web page based on one of three predefined ruleset or a user-defined ruleset. It offers suggestions for improving the page's performance, summarizes the page's components, displays statistics about the page, and provides tools for performance analysis, including Smush.it™ and JSLint.